# Xamarin Forms WebView content does not stay loaded on android when navigating between tabs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms 4.0 preview 4.

I have top tabs(using Shell), and each tab has a WebView in it.

In iOS, all the webviews in each tab load at the start, and you can swap between any tabs and all the webviews stay loaded.

In Android, they only stay loaded if you swap back and forth between adjacent tabs without going to another tab, and otherwise the browser reloads the page.

Is there a way I can have the webviews in android retain their content without reloading?

For example, if there are four tabs,
Navigate to tab 1, then tab 2, then back and forth to tab 1 and 2, and it all stays loaded.

Navigate to tab 2 then 3, then back and forth, stays loaded.

Navigate to 1, 2, then 3, then back to 1, and 1 content is gone and the webview starts loading the page again.

2 - > 4, loads the content again.

Comment: You could override the `OnAppearing` method and make that only load the content the first time. Just to know, why do you have so many webviews on a mobile app?

Comment: You can use Tabbedpage and get the index of currentPage in method OnCurrentPageChanged And for example  if the index equals 1(second page) , use the messagecenter to send message to the page if it is need to load again .

Comment: @FabriBertani How can I make it only load it the first time in OnAppearing?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I don't want it to ever load the page again, that's what I'm trying to prevent. In android only, it reloads the webviews.

Comment: @Kyle put a flag `var firstTime = true; if (firstTime) { ... firstTime = false; };` something like that

Comment: @FabriBertani but what would be the code to stop it from loading? nothing in onappearing is causing it to reload, onappearing is empty. the webview only refreshes it self on android only.

Comment: Default value of OffscreenPageLimit ([android platform specific property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.platformconfiguration.androidspecific.tabbedpage.offscreenpagelimit?view=xamarin-forms)) is 3. It shouldn't recreate if you swipe between 3 adjacent tabs. You can increase the limit, I only recommend it if you don't have heavy animations/list on any of the pages.

Comment: @shanranm Thanks, this sounds promising! How do I go about changing this property with Shell...? A little confused.